# lightbox type thing that makes images a percentage of browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I cannot add scrollbars to lightbox. Just not an option for my website right now at all. To have my really big images fit on any screen, in a lightbox type pop-up, I was wondering if someone had a reference to something like lightbox that could tell the height of the browser, and make the total height of the image the same, so the image never goes below the fold. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox does this by default. Even if your on your mobile the photos will show up without going outside the viewable area!!